# Modify Rows With Duplicate Values in a Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Right now, I am working with this dataframe..

| Name | DateSolved | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | 12/3 | 100 |
| Tim | 12/4 | 50 |
| Jo | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jonny | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jimmy | 12/8 | 10 |
| Tim | 12/8 | 10 |

At this moment, if there are duplicate names in the dataset, I just drop the oldest one (by date) from the dataframe by utilizing  `df.sort_values('DateSolved').drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')` leading to a dataset like this

| Name | DateSolved | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jo | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jonny | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jimmy | 12/8 | 10 |
| Tim | 12/8 | 10 |

However, instead of dropping the oldest one, I wish to keep it but give it a 50% points reduction. Something like this

| Name | DateSolved | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | 12/3 | 50 (-50%) |
| Tim | 12/4 | 25 (-50%) |
| Jo | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jonny | 12/5 | 25 |
| Jimmy | 12/8 | 10 |
| Tim | 12/8 | 10 |

How could I go about doing this? I cannot find a way to both FIND the duplicates based on "Name" and then change the value of the "POINTS" column in the same row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for select all duplicates withot last, select column `Points` and divide by `2`:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated('Name', keep='last'), 'Points'] /= 2
print (df)
    Name DateSolved  Points
0  Jimmy       12/3    50.0
1    Tim       12/4    25.0
2     Jo       12/5    25.0
3  Jonny       12/5    25.0
4  Jimmy       12/8    10.0
5    Tim       12/8    10.0
```